# Footer div pushed down too far & taking to much space

Tags: html, css, flexbox, footer, css-grid

Im having a little trouble with a practice project, Im almost complete but my div footer is being pushed all the way down and is taking up too much space. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Uniondale Public Libary</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="uplstyle.css">
</head>
<body>
<!-- top bar -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="logo-pic">
            <img src="https://uniondalelibrary.org/themes/Glass/images/logo.gif">
    </div>
<!-- nav bar -->    
    <div class="navbar">
        <div id="contain-nav">
            <ul id="nav-list">
                <li>Home</li>
                <li>online catalog</li>
                <li> Research Databases</li>
                <li>Newsletters</li>
                <li>Libary Information</li>
                <li>Libray History</li>
                <li>contact us</li>
            </ul>
            <p id="date">January 20 2020</p>
            <hr id="nav-hr">
        </div>

    </div>
<!-- Empty style nav -->
    <div class="fashion-nav">

    </div>
<!-- The Main body -->

        <div class="sidebar">
            <h1>navigation</h1>
            <ul id="sidenav">
                <li>Serivce</li>
                <li>Serivce</li>
                <li>Serivce</li>
                <li>Serivce</li>
                <li>Serivce</li>
                <li>Serivce</li>
            </ul>
            <hr id="sidenav-hr">
            <ul id="sidenav">
                <li>Serivce</li>
                <li>Serivce</li>
                <li>Serivce</li>
                <li>Serivce</li>
                <li>Serivce</li>
                <li>Serivce</li>
            </ul>
            <hr id="sidenav-hr">
            <ul id="sidenav">
                <li>Serivce</li>
                <li>Serivce</li>
                <li>Serivce</li>
                <li>Serivce</li>
                <li>Serivce</li>
                <li>Serivce</li>
            </ul>
            <hr id="sidenav-hr">
        </div>

<!-- welcome box -->

    <div class="welcome main-cmn">
        <h4>welcome</h4>
        <p><a href="">Uniondale Libary services</a></p>
    </div>
<!-- Event Keeper -->

    <div class="evnt-kpr main-cmn">
        <h4>EventKeeper</h4>
    </div>
<!-- Libary Hours -->
    <div class="hours-opt main-cmn">
        <h4>Libary Hours</h4>
    </div>
<!-- Free Digital Magazines  -->
    <div class="free-stuff main-cmn">
        <h4>Free Digital Magazines</h4>
    </div>
<!-- Libary app -->
    <div class="libary-app main-cmn">
        <h4>Libary App</h4>
    </div>
<!-- New Language Database -->
    <div class="newlang-db main-cmn">
        <h4>New Language Database</h4>
    </div>
<!-- Free Ancestry.com Database -->
    <div class="ancestry main-cmn">
        <h4>Free Ancestry.com Database</h4>
    </div>
<!-- Tutor Program -->
    <div class="tutor main-cmn">
        <h4>Free Tutor online program</h4>
    </div>
<!-- New online catalog -->
    <div class="new-ctlg main-cmn">
        <h4>New online catalog</h4>
    </div>
<!-- Right sidebar -->
    <div class="ctlg-search right-sidebar">
        <h4>catalog search</h4>
        <form>
            <input type="radio" name="">
            <label>Uniondale Libary</label>
            <input type="radio" name="">
            <label>Nassua Libraires</label>
            <select>
                <option>keyword</option>
                <option>keyword</option>
                <option>keyword</option>
                <option>keyword</option>
            </select>
            <input type="text" name="">
            <button>search</button>
        </form>
    </div>
<!-- Hours of op -->
    <div class="right-opt right-sidebar">
        <h4>Hours of opertation</h4>
        <ul>
            <li>Monday| 9AM-9PM</li>
            <li>Monday| 9AM-9PM</li>
            <li>Monday| 9AM-9PM</li>
            <li>Monday| 9AM-9PM</li>
            <li>Monday| 9AM-9PM</li>
            <li>Monday| 9AM-9PM</li>
            <li>Monday| 9AM-9PM</li>
            <li>Monday| 9AM-9PM</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<!-- Nassua e -->
    <div class="nassua-e right-sidebar">
        <h4>Nassua e</h4>
    </div>
<!-- Admin login -->
    <div class="admin-login right-sidebar">
        <h4>Administrative Login</h4>
        <form>
            <label>username</label>
            <input type="text" name="">
            <label>username</label>
            <input type="text" name="">
            <input type="checkbox" name="">
            <button>login</button>
        </form>
    </div>
<!-- Driving test -->
    <div class="drv-tst right-sidebar">
        <h4>Driving Tests</h4>
    </div>
<!-- Tutors.com -->
    <div class="web-tutor right-sidebar">
        <h4>Tutor.com</h4>
    </div>
<!-- Footer -->
    <div class="feet">
        <ul>
            <li>Monday,Wednesday & Thursday</li>
            <li>Monday,Wednesday & Thursday</li>
            <li>Monday,Wednesday & Thursday</li>
            <li>Monday,Wednesday & Thursday</li>
            <li>Monday,Wednesday & Thursday</li>
            <li>Monday,Wednesday & Thursday</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div> <!-- container -->
</body>
</html>
```

Css

```
/*elements global*/
html {
    background: #840000;
}

body {
    border: 2px solid #d10404;
    width: 90%;
    background: #d10404;
    margin: auto;
}

/*class and id's*/
.container {
    background: rgba(249, 102, 102, 1);
    width: 98%;
    margin: auto;
}

/*top bar*/


.logo-pic img {
    width: 100%
}


.navbar {
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-bottom: -21px;
}

#contain-nav ul{
    background: #ba0000;
    list-style: none;
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-flex;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 98%;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 0px 0px;
    margin: 0;
}


#nav-list li {
    padding: 10px;
}


#date {
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 35px;
    right: 10px;
}

#nav-hr {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 37px;
    width: 99%;
}

.fashion-nav {
    border: 3px solid #910202;
    height: 10px;
    background: #910202;
}


/*Side nav*/

.sidebar {
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 12%;
    border: 2px solid black;
    float: left;
}

/*Main body*/

.main-cmn {
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px;
}


/*right sidebar*/

.right-sidebar {
    float: right;
    width: 12%;
    clear: both;
    border: 2px solid black;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    bottom: 800px;
}

/*footer*/

.feet {
    background: transparent;
}

.feet ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline;
}

.feet li {
    float: left;
}
```

In css i tried resetting margin 0 and padding 0 and used.. bottom but  it doesn't work correctly. Css can be so tedious lol [Example1.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gifQb.png) [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9i0W.png)

Comment: These rules `position: relative; bottom: 800px;` cause the footer being pushed down, to fix it wrap right side blocks into a div container, and move it before all main area, then only float right that container, remember [**float first**](https://alistapart.com/article/css-floats-101), this [**codepen**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BYrXqy?editors=1100) is a working example.

Comment: Thank you i see where i went wrong now, I appreciate the help!